# Is there a way I can get text from a text widget between 2 different characters?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Making a simpler version of python in python, I want to be able to print text between two characters in a string from a textbox

I've tried code like `shell.get("1.7", '"')` but I get an error saying `_tkinter.TclError: bad text index """`
Here is a snippet of my current code:

```
from tkinter import *
import datetime

def run():
    print("File run " + str(datetime.datetime.now()))
    line = shell.get("1.0", END)
    #dont worry about ^ line for now (line 2 in run())
    if 'print "' in line:
        print (shell.get('1.7', '"'))

shell = ScrolledText(root, width=167, height=42)
shell.grid(column=0, row=1)
```

Heres what is in the shell
`print "Hello World"`

I just want something like: `print (shell.get(1.7, "<nearest quotation mark>")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tkinter Text widget has a [`search` method](https://web.archive.org/web/20201112033110/http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/text.htm#Tkinter.Text.search-method) which you can use to find the first occurrence of a pattern starting at an index.

In your case you would want to find the first `"` after the `1.7` index. To do this you can run:

```
shell.search('"', '1.7')
```

Integrated in your code that would be:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.scrolledtext import ScrolledText
import datetime

def run(event=None):
    print('File run ' + str(datetime.datetime.now()))
    line = shell.get("1.0", END)
    if 'print "' in line:
        print (shell.get('1.7', shell.search('"', '1.7')))

        
root = Tk()        
shell = ScrolledText(root, width=167, height=42)
shell.insert('1.0', 'print "print this" do not print this')
shell.grid(column=0, row=1)
shell.bind('<Button-1>', run)
root.mainloop()
```

Notice that I bound the `run` function to the left mouse button for demonstrative purposes.

Comment: THANKYOU!!!! This is probably the most productive moment in this project. It worked and it's amazing.